# 5 IP Addresses on a multi-homed NIC, 4 ping-able, what's wrong with the 5th?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip, subnet

Dell Server, broadcom NIC, 5 IP addresses all on the same subnet. Let's say 100.100.63.67-71. Windows Server 2003.

From another system on the 100.100.63.* subnet, I can ping all IP addresses no problem.

From a system on another subnet, say 100.100.58.*, I can ping all but one, the 100.100.63.70 address. It's in the middle of the IP range.

In Win2003 server, I specify the default gateway once as 100.100.63.1. Each individual IP has a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. I've verified they are all the same.

I'm stumped... why would 100.100.63.70 not respond to pings from outside it's subnet, while the others will?

Comment: Have you verified whether it is actually receiving the ICMP ping request by running tcpdump/wireshark or some other packet analyzer?

Comment: Have you tried ping 70 from the same network? You must decrease "point of failures" to identify (possible) single point

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what's separating the networks (firewall or router), but these would be the steps I'd take:-

- If the device between the subnets is a firewall, make sure that it's configured to allow traffic for the .70 IP.
- If firewall rules aren't the problem (or if the device is a router), check the ARP table. Try pinging the .70 IP from the firewall/router.
- Using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or similar) on the server, check to see if your ICMP packets are being received at all.

You don't say, but I'm assuming that you've tried from multiple devices on other subnets?

Comment: I think this is the most likely possibility. Whatever router connects the two subnets likely has some leftover configuration that blocks either the ping or the reply.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the router had a static mac address applied to that IP address, which was not the mac address of the NIC. Clearing the static entry immediately resolved the problem.

Answer (score -5):

> 5 IP addresses all on the same subnet. Let's say 100.100.63.67-71

Let's say - network 100.100.63.67-100.100.63.71 **can not exist at all**.

```
$ ipcalc 100.100.63.67-100.100.63.71
deaggregate 100.100.63.67 - 100.100.63.71
100.100.63.67/32
100.100.63.68/30
```

Write real data in order to get real answers!

Tracert from-to .70, ipconfig also welcomed. TiCL also totally correct - verify, that your get ICMP, you answer on ICMP, you have correct route table (you must anwser from the same interface, which received packet)

Edit: Before checking logical conditions (network settings), you have to check **physical** also **before** - cable, NIC-port, switch port

Comment: He specifically states they're 5 IPs **within a /24** when he says they have a mask of `255.255.255.0`.